# Is there a sql function to lookup/join elements within an array? Using Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have a table which has an array field of ids, and I want to replace the ids with names, but keep it in the same array format. 
I have a separate 'lookup' table with the ids & their corresponding names.
Since it's an array, I cannot do a simple join.
I've tried flattening the array field, then doing a simple join - which works - but then I don't know how to put it back into the same original array format. Are there any better ways of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION VLOOKUP(expr ANY TYPE, map ANY TYPE) AS ((
  IFNULL((SELECT name FROM UNNEST(map) WHERE id = expr), expr)
));  
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'aaa' other_fields, [STRUCT('456' AS id_field), STRUCT('3367'), STRUCT('xyz')] AS array_fields UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb', [STRUCT('56'), STRUCT('89')] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ccc', [STRUCT('40'), STRUCT('768'), STRUCT('8766'), STRUCT('abc')]
), `project.dataset.lookup_table` AS (
  SELECT '456' id, 'A' name UNION ALL
  SELECT '56', 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT '89', 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT '40', 'D'
)
SELECT t.* REPLACE(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT id_field, VLOOKUP(id_field, kv) AS desired_new_field
    FROM t.array_fields
  ) AS array_fields
)
FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
(SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id, name)) AS kv FROM `project.dataset.lookup_table`) arr
```

with result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have primary key in the table, you can flatten the array, and then group back on primary key using ARRAY_AGG to reconstruct an array.
Without primary key, you can still do INNER JOIN (but not OUTER JOINs) over elements of the array, i.e.

```
SELECT 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT STRUCT<id_field string, desired_id_field string>(id_field, desired_id_field) 
    FROM UNNEST(id_field) id_field 
    INNER JOIN lookup_table
    ON id_field = lookup_table.names) 
FROM main_table
```

You will still need to merge id_field and desired_id_field later to fill the gaps of ids which didn't match.